# backup the profile settings in Outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

How to backup the profile settings in Outlook 2007. The [post](http://www.outlook-tips.net/outlook-email-accounts/outlook-profile-file-prf/) says, there is no way to back up the profile settings in Outlook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Easy Transfer (migwiz.exe) allows you to back up Outlook settings. Just type "migwiz" into the search bar and follow the instructions. You can select which files are backed up.

Comment: Won't save your password but.

Comment: interesting, I hadn't noticed that. You are talking about an Outlook p/w correct? Because it does save the user log in info for the workstation itself, if you remain on the same domain.

Comment: The mail account passwords, if you have accounts off the home domain.  It's a security feature.

Answer (score 2):

[this page](http://www.backuphowto.info/how-to-backup-restore-data-e-mail-account-settings-outlook-2007) says you can do it by backing up a registry value

> Start > Run > type ‘regedit’ & Locate the following path in your
>   ‘Registry Editor’ HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows
>   NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles\Outlook
>
> Now right click on the key outlook and select option: Export and save
>   .reg files to your desired location. You can run the same file while
>   restoring your outlook. This will restore your old outlook profile
>   with all your email accounts settings and rules. You will need to
>   enter your password as Password is not stored into .reg file.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use batch script when backing up users Outlook to a network location... use this as the batch source, and save the script to a location on a network drive or portable device where you can store your backups. There more to backing up outlook than just your registry values...

%~dp0users\%username% -- This uses the location of the script to determine where backups go.

I use robocopy in this manner so that users can't see each others backups on the share (because of permissions...)

This is part of a MUCH LARGER script that i shortened up for Outlook purposes only... and is still a work in progress, but for now it prevents users from having to setup Outlook at all when moving from one machine to the next.

If anyone has any input I'd be glad to hear.

```
:: Script Start
@echo off

set /p begin="Press Enter to begin the backup process"
set trigs= /E /XJ /XO /TEE /V /MIR /SEC
set backLocation="%~dp0users\%username%"

echo Closing Outlook...
TASKKILL /F /IM OUTLOOK.exe

echo Backing up Outlook data...
:: This copies all Outlook .pst's (personal\archived folders) to the backup location
robocopy "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook" "%backLocation%\Outlook\pst" %trigs% /XF *.obi *.tmp *.oab *.dat *.ost /V /log:%userprofile%\Desktop\Outlook_log.txt

:: This copies outlook .NK2 files (Auto-Complete data) to the backup location
robocopy "%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Outlook" "%backLocation%\Outlook\nk2" %trigs% /XF *.srs *.xml *.dat /V

echo Backing up Outlook Config...
:: This makes a copy of the Outlook configuration from registry to be used later.     
:: Our users have profiles on the D: partition, as C: is blocked from access by end user.
:: Creating the .reg locally to the system on D:, then copying it to the backup location
:: has been the only way to get it where it needs to be, for me. YMMV
regedit /e %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\Outlook_Config.reg "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles"
copy "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\Outlook_Config.reg" "%backLocation%\Outlook\"

echo/
echo Outlook Backup Complete!

@pause
:Script End
```

Comment: Hi Joshua. You need to indent code by 4 spaces, which you can do by selecting it and pressing `Ctrl-K`, or the `{}` button in our editor. I fixed the post for you.